# transform any class into a [String:Any] array you can save into Cloud firecast document

Tags: swift4

So when you want to write a custom class into Cloud firestore you need to transform your class into a something of the form [String: Any] where any has to be of the supported types https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

String, Int, double, array, etc.

If you are programming in Java you can just save your class into Cloud Firestore and Cloud Firestore automatically transform this into a value type supported by Firestore.

I will like to create generic functions that do this. 
`func getValueType<T>()-> [String:Any]`

Or maybe to be more precise, something like the Codable and Decodable protocol for JASON objects.

Comment: Your title is confusing because `[String: Any]` is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: Yes, I meant dictionary, I don't think I am allowed to edit the title.